# Displaying text from dataset in console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display in console the particular text value from dataset. I use mouseover and mouseout events and, using loop, I'm able to display all data-texts but don't know how to make js display just single one, tied with hoovered text.

Please take a look at code below. I'd like to see in console "Tooltip1" while hovering tooltips[0], "Tooltip2" while tooltips[1] and so on. Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. <span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip1"> Etiam ullamcorper.</span>Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. <span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip 2">Maecenas malesuada elit lectus</span> felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula.<span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip 3">Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna.</span> Vestibulum 
</p>
</body>
</html>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip");
var tooltipsValue = [];
console.log(tooltips);

for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {

var dataTags = tooltips[i].dataset.text;
tooltipsValue.push(dataTags);

//console.log(i);
//console.log(tooltipsValue);
//console.log(dataTags);
//tooltips[i].dataset.text;
//var dataTag = tooltips[i].dataset.text;
//console.log(tooltips[i].dataset.text);

tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  //console.log("text while mouseover");
  //console.log(tooltipsValue[i]);

});
tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  //console.log("text after mouseout");
});

}  

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your approach, last tooltip value will be displayed all the time as value of `i` is `tooltips.length-1`. Reason is by the time event takes place, for loop iteration is over.

`this.dataset.text` will always refer to current element on which `mouseover` and `mouseout` is taking place.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip");
  var tooltipsValue = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
    var dataTags = tooltips[i].dataset.text;
    tooltipsValue.push(dataTags);
    tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      console.log(this.dataset.text);
    });
    tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      console.log(this.dataset.text);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. <span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip1"> Etiam ullamcorper.</span>Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. <span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip 2">Maecenas malesuada elit lectus</span> felis, malesuada ultricies.
  Curabitur et ligula.<span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip 3">Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna.</span> Vestibulum
</p>
```

*You can use [`closure`](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) to achieve the same results, **A closure is an inner function that has access to the outer (enclosing) function’s variables***

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip");
  var tooltipsValue = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
    var dataTags = tooltips[i].dataset.text;
    tooltipsValue.push(dataTags);
    tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        console.log(tooltips[i].dataset.text)
      }
    })(i));
    tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseout', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        console.log(tooltips[i].dataset.text)
      }
    })(i));
  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. <span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip1"> Etiam ullamcorper.</span>Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. <span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip 2">Maecenas malesuada elit lectus</span> felis, malesuada ultricies.
  Curabitur et ligula.<span class="tooltip" data-text="Tooltip 3">Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna.</span> Vestibulum
</p>
```

Comment: Would you add the comment of what was changed and how it should work?